# FAIL: col.insert({}, cb) vs SUCCESS col.insert({}, () => cb())

Tags: javascript, mongodb, async.js

Looking for an explanation. Tried variations without fat arrow, same results.
Using

"mongodb": "^2.2.24",

the following code doesn't work (I load the values later and they're not there)

```
addCollections(data, cb) {
    var names = Object.keys(data);
    async.each(names, (name, cb1) => {
        db.createCollection(name).then((collection) => {
            collection.insert(data[name], cb1);
        }).catch(cb1);
    }, cb)
},
```

but this code *does* work:

```
addCollections(data, cb) {
    var names = Object.keys(data);
    async.each(names, (name, cb1) => {
        db.createCollection(name).then((collection) => {
            collection.insert(data[name], (a, b) => {
                // reverted this comment bc Im debugging this
                cb1();
            })
        }).catch(cb1);
    }, cb);
},
```

The following also works:

```
addCollections(data, cb) {
    var names = Object.keys(data);
    async.each(names, (name, cb1) => {
        db.createCollection(name).then((collection) => {
            collection.insert(data[name], cb1);
        }).catch(cb1);
    }, () => {
        setTimeout(function() {
            cb()
        }, 10);
    })
},
```

Call stack (using lab as test lib) as requested by @Adam:

```
execute(fixture, verify, cb) {
    db.connect(() => {
        db.drop(() => {
            db.addCollections(fixture, () => {
                this.executeNode(fixture, verify, cb);
            });
        });
    });
},

executeNode(fixture, verify, cb) {
    var injectOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'myUrl
    };

    server.inject(injectOptions, function (response) {
        verify(response.result);
        db.close(cb);
    });
},

test('default', (done) => {
    fb.execute(fixture, verify, done);
});
```

Comment: Don't use promises together with `async.js`

Comment: The first should be correct indeed. Can you show us how you call it and handle errors?

Comment: I'm curious, why no promises with async?

Comment: Because they are different interfaces that are really hard to combine without mistakes. You have so many callbacks in your codes, and it's *really hard* to see which ones of them use the nodeback convention (taking error and result arguments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only explanation I can come up with is that `collection.insert` calls its callback with a truthy argument; i.e. it results in an error if we assume the nodeback convention.

That your test is failing is therefore *expected*.

So why do the other two codes "work"?

- In the second snippet, `() => { cb1(); }` as a callback for `insert` (implicitly?) ignores the error, regardless whether it is called with one it never passes anything to `cb1`.
- In the third snippet, the `async.each` will fail (correctly) and call its callback `() => { setTimeout(function(){cb()}, 10); }` with the error - whcih again implicitly ignores it and never passes it to `cb`. The timeout is unnecessary for this, `each(…, () => cb())` would have had the same result.

Comment: You are right. `data` is a list of objects, each representing a collection (an array of objects). Some 'collections' were empty, and insert([]) returns an error. It was irrelevant to my application, therefore the other examples worked fine. `db.addCollections(fixture, () => {` this is where I should catch the error. My bad for forgetting to handle it.